# How to copy one cell (A1), paste it 640 times, copy the next cell (A2), paste it 640 times directly below

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA and I'm trying to write a macro that will copy 1 cell in Column L, paste it 640 times down in column A and repeat this 176 times such that after each 640 copy/paste cycle, the macro will move onto the next cell in Column L, rinse and repeat.

What I've got so far is the code below which essentially does what I want it to do BUT only does it twice-- I think the gap is that I don't know how to properly apply the loop twice (once to say copy 640 times and the second to say once you're done copying 640 times, go to the next cell in column L and start again).

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 2
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 11).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -11).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -11).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next i
End Sub
```

Thank you for the help and apologies in advance if I'm missing a thread where this was already answered (searched through quite a few, but cant find it).

Comment: in A1:  `=INDEX(L:L,INT((ROW(A1)-1)/640)+1)` and copy down.

Comment: Thank you! This worked!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop like this

```
Sub CopyDown()

    Const NUM_ROWS As Long = 5 'or whatever
    Dim c As Range, rng As Range, i As Long

    Set c = Range("L1")
    Set rng = Range("A1").Resize(NUM_ROWS, 1)

    For i = 1 To 5 'or whatever
        rng.Value = c.Value
        Set rng = rng.Offset(NUM_ROWS, 0)
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Next i

End Sub
```